# Is it true that every graph with $n$ vertices in which $\delta(G)\geq\frac{n}{2}-1$ has Hamiltionian path?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Is it true that every graph with $n$ vertices in which $\delta(G)\geq\frac{n}{2}-1$ has Hamiltionian path? $\delta(G)$ is the minimum degree of $G$.

Comment: What is delta of G?

Comment: Vertex with minimum number of edges coming to/from it.

Comment: You should at the very least specify that the graph is connected. Otherwise a graph with two vertices and no edges is one of many counterexamples.

Answer (score 3):

*A laconic answer.*

Y

*An explanation of the laconic answer.*

“Y” means No, that is a counterexample is a star $K_{1,3}$.

[image]

*A bonus answer.*  On the other hand, if $n\ge 3$ and $\delta(G)\ge \frac n2$ then $G$ has a Hamiltonian *cycle* (see, for instance, Corollary at the last page of slides of the lecture “[Round trips](http://www.electronics.lnu.edu.ua/fileadmin/konferences/kursmatem/lec01-roundtrips.pdf)” in Algorithmic Graph Theory by Joachim Spoerhase and Alexander Wolff). This also allows us to prove if $n\ge 2$ and $\delta(G)\ge \frac n2-\frac 12$ then $G$ has a Hamiltonian path. Indeed,  let $G^*$ be $G$ with an additional vertex $v^*$ adjacent to every vertex of $G$. Then $$\delta(G^*)=\delta(G)+1\ge  \frac n2+\frac 12=\frac{n+1}{2}.$$ Thus $G^*$  has a Hamiltonian cycle. When we remove the vertex $v^*$ from the cycle we obtain a Hamiltonian path for $G$.